# In Keras, how do I count the exact number of correct guesses during model evaluation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've use Keras to try to make a basic neural network and I'm using some census data. The network is supposed to identify whether or not an individual makes "<=50K" or ">50K" per year. I have the accuracy which is fine but I also want to know how many of each instance was correct.

So the four parameters I want to count are:

How many times did the model guess "<=50K" when it should have been ">50K"?

How many times did the model guess "<=50K" and it was "<=50K"?

How many times did the model guess ">50K" when it should have been "<=50K"?

How many times did the model guess ">50K" and it was ">50K"?

```
#define model architecture
model = Sequential()
n_cols = train_x.shape[1] 
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_cols,)))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

#compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#fit model on training data
model.fit(train_x, train_y,
    nb_epoch=50, verbose=1)

#evaluate model on test data
accuracy = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=1)
print("loss: ", accuracy[0]*100)
print("accuracy: ", accuracy[1]*100)
```

Comment: Please notice that you actually have a classification problem, and you are approaching it as a regression one, which is plain wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you define "<=50K" as class 0 or *negative*, and ">50K" as class 1 or *positive*, you are looking for the following metrics:

How many times did the model guess "<=50K" when it should have been ">50K"? corresponds to `tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives`

How many times did the model guess "<=50K" and it was "<=50K"? corresponds to `tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives`

How many times did the model guess ">50K" when it should have been "<=50K"? corresponds to `tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives`

How many times did the model guess ">50K" and it was ">50K"? corresponds to `tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives`

Edit: You would add these to your code in the following manner:

```
...

# Define metrics
fn = tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()
tn = tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives()
fp = tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives()
tp = tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives()

# Get model predictions for test data
test_preds = model(test_x)

# Convert labels for test data to categorical
test_y = tf.cast(test_y, tf.int32)

# Update metrics
fn.update_state(y_true=test_y, y_pred=test_preds)
tn.update_state(y_true=test_y, y_pred=test_preds)
fp.update_state(y_true=test_y, y_pred=test_preds)
tp.update_state(y_true=test_y, y_pred=test_preds)

# Print results
tf.print(fn.result())
tf.print(tn.result())
tf.print(fp.result())
tf.print(tp.result())
```